# Multilinear loss in Uniform-Exponential model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

> Let a prior
>   $\pi(\theta)=\frac{1}{3}(\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(\theta)+\mathbb{I}_{[2,3]}(\theta)+\mathbb{I}_{[4,5]}(\theta))$
>   and $f(x\mid\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta x}$. Taking the multilinear loss 
>   $$L_{k_1,k_2}(\theta,\delta) = \begin{cases} k_2(\theta-\delta), &\theta>\delta, \\
> k_1(\theta-\delta), & \theta\leq\delta  \end{cases}$$
>   show that the Bayes estimator is  not unique.

I know that $f(x\mid\theta)\sim \exp(\theta)$ and $\pi(\theta)$ is a sum of Uniform distributions such that
$$\pi(\theta)\in (0,1)
$$
and

> Proposition: A Bayes estimator associated with prior $\pi$ and
>   multilinear loss is the $\frac{k_1}{k_1+k_2}$ fractile of
>   $\pi(\theta\mid x)$

$$\pi(\theta\mid x)\propto\theta e^{-\theta x}\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(\theta)+\theta e^{-\theta x}\mathbb{I}_{[2,3]}(\theta)+\theta e^{-\theta x}\mathbb{I}_{[4,5]}(\theta)$$

I don't understand right this proposition, I don't need to find $E[\pi(\theta\mid x)$? 
The estimator would be $$\frac{k_1}{k_1+k_2}E[\pi(\theta\mid x)]?$$

To show that is not unique I need to construct two estimators, or there is another way?

I'm trying to use this theorem

[image]

but I don't understand this well , is just the fractile of posterior?

Comment: If by "$E[\pi(\theta\mid x)]$" you mean $E[\theta\mid x]$, that would be the Bayes estimator under squared-error loss.  You need to find the posterior expected loss, using the loss function that is given.  The value of $\theta$ that minimizes that would be the Bayes estimator. $\qquad$

Comment: BTW, I would say "piecewise linear" rather than "multilinear". $\qquad$

Comment: Did you mean $\theta e^{-\theta x} \mathbb I_{2,3}(\theta)$ where you have $e^{-\theta x} \mathbb I_{2,3}(\theta)$? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, is a typo sorry. If possible take a look again